# Sonar: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: database, jenkins, sonarqube

am running  sonar from Jenkins.
Sonar version is 2.13
I got this exception

please help me

```
[ERROR] [21:49:15.205] JDBC begin failed
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 7,028,219 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 16 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
    at
```

The Jenkins job of sonar almost ran for 1:30 mins is the reason for jdbc connection loose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you connect to the same JDBC URL, using a standard SQL navigator product like [squirrel](http://www.squirrelsql.org/)?

Perhaps it's something obvious like the database is shutdown.

## Update

The following thread describes the same problem:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=991141

In that case it was a permissions issue on the MySQL server. The client IP addresses were restricted.

Comment: i am able to connect jbdc url with client software